# Homology of group rings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-rings

Let $\mathbb Z G$ be the group ring of $G$. Denote by $\mathbb Z G ^{gp}$ the universal enveloping group of the monoid $(\mathbb Z G,*)$, i.e. the fundamental group of the classyfiyng space of $(\mathbb Z G,*)$. How to compute $H_* (\mathbb Z G ^{gp},\mathbb Z )=H_* (B (\mathbb Z G,*),\mathbb Z )$ in terms of $H_* (G,\mathbb Z )$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
I want to obtain in some canonical way a group H from $\mathbb Z G$ with the same homology groups as G has

Comment: $(\Bbb ZG, *)$ has a zero element ($0 * g = 0$ for all $g \in \Bbb ZG$). That relation forces the universal enveloping monoid to be zero.